# embed a Jar thats an jframe into html

Tags: java, html, swing, jframe

I have a problem, I want to embed a Jar into my html code.
The problem is that I use JFrames and not in my java Code. If i use Applets what was an example for a solution my Programm doesnt work anymore because of diffrent error messages,their is no Problem with set Title, so I wanted to ask if their is any way to embed my Jar file into my website without making it to an Applet.

Comment: With `jar` your refer to a [`JavaArchive`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAR_(file_format))? I am not sure what you are trying to do here, you might want to provide some example code.

Comment: Short answer - don't. Java is no longer supported in browsers (long live html5) for a number of reasons